# Uncorrect work equal assembly code (x86_64 linux)

Tags: linux, memory-management, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to write a simple compiler. My language can calculate an arithmetic expression using float numbers, save a variable and print a variable. In the first version of my compiler all my calculations only using a `push` and `pop`. Then I make calculate with call absolute stack address. I have not allocated memory with `sub rsp`, but rather I used `[rsp-8*x]`, where `x` is number of value on the stack, like a `push` and `pop`. But the issue is that it does not work with `pow` function from libc. I can't understand, what I'm doing wrong.

I refactored the code a bit, for your convenience.

My first version in assembly (nasm syntax):

```
[bits 64]
global _start
extern printf
extern pow

section .data
    printf_format db '%lf', 10, 0
section .text
_start:
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 0x20

    mov rax, 0x4000000000000000
    push rax
    mov rax, 0x4000000000000000
    push rax
    mov rax, 0x4008000000000000
    push rax

    movsd xmm0, qword [rsp+8]
    movsd xmm1, qword [rsp]
    call pow
    movsd qword [rsp+8], xmm0

    add rsp, 8
    movsd xmm0, qword [rsp+8]
    movsd xmm1, qword [rsp]
    call pow

    mov rdi, printf_format
    mov rax, 1
    call printf

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

My second version:

```
[bits 64]
global _start
extern printf
extern pow

section .data
    printf_format db '%lf', 10, 0
section .text
    _start:
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 0x20

    mov rax, 0x4000000000000000
    mov qword [rsp-8*1], rax
    mov rax, 0x4000000000000000
    mov qword [rsp-8*2], rax
    mov rax, 0x4008000000000000
    mov qword [rsp-8*3], rax

    movsd xmm0, qword [rsp-8*2]
    movsd xmm1, qword [rsp-8*3]
    call pow
    movsd qword [rsp-8*2], xmm0

    movsd xmm0, qword [rsp-8*1]
    movsd xmm1, qword [rsp-8*2]
    call pow

    mov rdi, printf_format
    mov rax, 1
    call printf

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

I compile and link this with:

```
nasm -f elf64 ex.asm
ld -lc -lm -m elf_x86_64 -I/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ex.o -o ex
```

In the last version of my compiler, I wrote the call with `[rsp+8*x]` and allocated with `sub rsp`, and the problem was solved.

My question is: Why that change I made solved this problem?

Comment: I attempted to improved the grammar and wording of your question and make it easier to understand, but clearly there are some sentences that still need some improvement, such as "**I used allocating calculate expression to assembly function**, and all my calculating only used a push and pop". I didn't change those expressions because I didn't understand the meaning of them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I delete some not matter sentence.